# Missing new line when downloading a text file using python's request package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am using the following code for downloading a csv file from a remote http server:

```
with contextlib.closing(requests.get("http://some_url/file.csv", stream= True)) as response, open('/tmp/archivo.csv', 'wb') as output_file:               
        for chunk in response.iter_lines(chunk_size=1024*8):
            if chunk:       
                print(chunk)
                output_file.write(chunk)
```

Everything seems to work, the output on the screen is:

```
b'Code,Description'
b'"1","Some"'
b'"2","Few"'
b'"3","human"'
....
```

But the file is:

```
$ cat /tmp/archivo.csv                                                                                                                          
Code,Description"1","Some""2","Few""3","human"...
```

I think that the issue is related to the new line encoding between Windows, GNU/Linux and Mac, but I don't know how to specify that in the code just showed.

The problem is not related to opening the file in 'wb' mode, is I made the changes needed

```
with contextlib.closing(requests.get("http://some_url/file.csv", stream= True)) as response, open('/tmp/archivo.csv', 'w') as output_file:               
        for chunk in response.iter_lines(chunk_size=1024*8):
            if chunk:       
                print(chunk.decode('utf-8'))
                output_file.write(chunk.decode('utf-8'))
```

The output on the screen changes,

```
'Code,Description'
'"1","Some"'
'"2","Few"'
'"3","human"'
...
```

but the file doesn't

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing newlines because `print()` automatically terminates every output with a newline. Compare your output to

```
print(chunk.decode('utf-8'), end='')
```

which specifically does not terminate with newlines.

To correctly insert newlines into `output_file` you can use

```
output_file.write(chunk.decode('utf-8') + '\n')
```

or iterate over chunks instead of lines using

```
for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024*8):
    if chunk:
        output_file.write(chunk)
```

Comment: Is this the better way of do it?

Comment: You either iterate over lines and append the newline manually, or you iterate over chunks which contain newlines but printing will be messy.

Comment: Coudn't find this in the docs; thanks for confirming that iter_lines() is *supposed* to strip newlines.